# "Stacking" canvas elements

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So I made an application which basically draws shapes and text over an image. To do this, I used a canvas (I'll call it imageCanvas from now) and everything works fine. However, I needed to add a function which draws (and hides/shows through a checkbox) gridlines over the image AND the imageCanvas. So I made a new canvas called boxCanvas and put it on top of the imageCanvas.

I used two viewboxes because they need to be scalable, but the problem is when I try to add elements through code-behind on the second canvas, the gridlines won't show.

```
// XAML
<Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="9" Grid.Row="5">
    <Canvas x:Name="imageCanvas">
    </Canvas>
</Viewbox>

<Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="9" Grid.Row="5">
    <Canvas x:Name="boxCanvas">
    </Canvas>
</Viewbox>

// CODE-BEHIND
// I had to cut the entire code because it's too long, but here's the gist:
// 1. Set the image
BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
bitmap.BeginInit();
bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(imagePath);
bitmap.EndInit();
detectedImage.Source = bitmap;

// 2. Draw shapes and text
var rect = new Rectangle
{
    StrokeThickness = 3 * lineWidth,
    Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(SetColor),
    Width = x.width,
    Height = x.height
};
Canvas.SetLeft(rect, x.left);
Canvas.SetTop(rect, x.top);
ca.Children.Add(rect);

var text = new TextBlock
{
    Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White),
    Text = "ID:" + inc,
    FontSize = 12 * lineWidth
};
Canvas.SetLeft(text, (double)x.left);
Canvas.SetTop(text, (double)x.top - text.FontSize - 4);
ca.Children.Add(text);

// 3. Draw grid lines
private void DrawLines(BitmapImage image, int strideX, int strideY, int unitX, int unitY)
{
    var rect = new Rectangle
        {
            StrokeThickness = 4,
            Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Aqua),
            Width = unitX,
            Height = unitY
        };
        Canvas.SetLeft(rect, ox);
        Canvas.SetTop(rect, oy);
        boxCanvas.Children.Add(rect);
}
```

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: *"Any idea why this happens?"*- the code is not full enough. See [mcve]. Maybe you do not call `DrawLines()` at all.

Comment: You should not have two Viewboxes. Either draw all elements into a single Canvas in a single Viewbox, or add `boxCanvas` as child of `imageCanvas`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I figured it out. I just forgot to set the canvas width and height in the code behind.

Thank you!